# Spawning a task in c# and knowing when its finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, wait, thread-sleep

I have this compress video task that uses an external program to do it in c#.  It takes some time for this compression to finish and the file to write out.  I don't want to run the next piece of code until I know the external operation has had time to finish.

Do I want to do a simple Thread.sleep(some guess); and then run the next line of code or is there a better way?

this is how I am doing the compressing of the video:

```
 try
        {
            String finalCommand = "";
            String thePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
            finalCommand ="-i " + fileName + " -s 320x240 -b 300k -r 30 -f avi " + thePath + "\\C" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ffmpegcmd = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\ffmpeg.exe",
                 "-i \""  +  fileName + "\" -s 320x240 -b 300k -r 30 -f avi \"" + thePath + "\\C" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "\"");

            ffmpegcmd.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ffmpegcmd);
            LogUtil.writeLog("About to wait for FFMPEGCMD process");
            p.WaitForExit();
            success = true;
            LogUtil.writeLog("FFMPEGCMD process exited perfectly!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtil.writeLog("ERROR compressing and using FFMPEG");
            success = false;
        }
```

though I realize I am not sure if this is doing a process/thread on its own hmm.

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're using fully qualified classnames everywhere? To my mind it would be easier to read if you just had using directives for System.Diagnostics and System.IO.

Comment: and if this is going to be used in a commercial app check out FFMpeg licensing http://ffmpeg.org/shame.html

Comment: @codejoy are you running the code above in a separate thread or not? you already have a "p.WaitForExit()" which does exactly what it says -waits for the external process to finish - so unless you're running the whole method in a different thread, you're already waiting for the external process to complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a new thread, you can just call [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx):

```
Thread.Join(otherThread);
```

... possibly with a timeout.

In .NET 4 you can use the Task Parallel Library (creating a `Task` or `Task<TResult>`) and then call [`Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235604.aspx). (If you're using .NET 4, the TPL is definitely the way to go in general - you can do *lots* of stuff with it.)

Both of these approaches are *blocking* - they will stop the waiting thread from doing anything else until the other task has completed; this isn't something you want to do in the UI thread. So *if* this is in the context of a user interface, it would be best to use a callback instead - make the other task call back into the UI thread when it's done; that can kick off the next piece of code.

EDIT: The code you've shown is creating a new *process*, not a new *thread*. You may *also* be doing it in a new thread, but you haven't shown that. It's also still unclear whether this is all taking place in a UI such as Windows Forms or WPF, or whether it's just a console app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at msdn: [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public void compressVideo(obkect o)
   {
      \\ code
    }

    Thread t = new Thread( new threathStart( \\ pass the method that you want to execute on this thread...
    t.start(parameterYouWishtoPas);
    while(t.IsAlive)
    {
       Thread.sleep(1);
     }
     \\ this line will not execute untill thread t finishes executing...
```

Comment: Just make sure that you compressVideoMethod does terminate. Otherwise you'll be stuck on an infinite loop. My code might be eassier to implement but @jon skeet technique looks better to me...

Comment: In what way is this code easier than calling `Thread.Join(t)`, which is also more efficient? There's no point in waking up repeatedly...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't doing the sleep suggestion that Tano suggested...there is no reason to occupy the CPU just for waiting for another thread (busy wait).
Jon's suggestion is what you need.

If the compression thread, for some reason, never ends, than I suggest you try using [reset events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).
Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0420__Thread/Useamanualeventobject.htm)